# PHP Regex String Allow Chinese Word, alphanumeric & few special characters

Tags: php, regex

hi can help in below code to do validation in username text field.
Allow chinese word, alphanumeric and special characters "_" and "-" only.

Added:
I'm trying to create a validation for a username text field, allow chinese word, alphanumeric & "-" & "_" . I'm trying to figure out the regex as below, but it does not work as i expected. Anyone can hep.

```
if (preg_match("/[~`!@#$%^&*()+={}\[\]|\\:;\"'<>,.?\/]/", "小明@ah meng"))
{
  echo "invalid";
}
else
{
  echo "valid";
}
```

Comment: How is that regex relevant to your actual question? Just an arbitrary copy and paste that you want "fixed"? Any other attempts, or something to concretize your issue?

Comment: Im trying to create a validation for a text field in web, as above. But the regex validation does not work as i expected. Can help

Comment: @WhiteCoffee: Do you want to exclude any other alphabets other than Chinese? I mean, `\p{L}` is not suitable for you? Try `'/[^\p{L}\p{N}_-]/u'` with your current code. *it does not work as i expected* - do you mean `"小明@ah meng"` returns `valid`? Add `/u` flag to your regex.

Comment: 1. Special character allow only "_" and "-" (underscore & dash)
2. Allow A-Za-z0-9 alphanumeric
3. Allow chinese character.

So basicallly i want to exclude this "'~`!@#$%^&*()+={}[]|\:;"'<>,.?/"]

Comment: Have a look, [this code](https://ideone.com/WsRBG0) says your input is invalid. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

The [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) comprehends multiple code points from CJK. Since PCRE allows [Unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) with the `\p` token, you can match most Chinese characters with `\p{Han}`.

#### Code:

```php
<?php
    $str = "小明ahmeng";

    $regex = '/^[-_A-Za-z0-9\p{Han}]+$/u';   // notice spaces are not included

    if (preg_match( $regex, $str)) {
        echo "valid";
    } else {
        echo "invalid";
    }
?>
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ADN87285)

Also, don't forget to set the [`/u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) when you're working with UTF-8 encoded strings.